# Save 3 images per second from a live stream

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm attempting to use streamlink and ffmpeg to save 3 images per second from a twitch livestream. The goal is to be able to analyze the images as quickly as possible.

So far, I've tried the following:

`streamlink https://www.twitch.tv/dakotaz 720p --hls-segment-threads=3 --hls-live-edge 1 --output=- --player-no-close | ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -r 3 testing/%04d.jpg`

This basically accomplishes the goal, but the images seem to be saved to disk in batches. Sometimes there is a 6 second gap between when the batches of images are saved to disk.

`-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   27951 Oct 26 11:47:58 2018 0502.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   29254 Oct 26 11:47:58 2018 0503.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   29105 Oct 26 11:47:58 2018 0504.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   26540 Oct 26 11:47:58 2018 0505.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   26706 Oct 26 11:47:59 2018 0506.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   27283 Oct 26 11:47:59 2018 0507.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   28786 Oct 26 11:47:59 2018 0508.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   28118 Oct 26 11:47:59 2018 0509.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   28020 Oct 26 11:47:59 2018 0510.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   27542 Oct 26 11:47:59 2018 0511.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   24700 Oct 26 11:47:59 2018 0512.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   23952 Oct 26 11:47:59 2018 0513.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   23744 Oct 26 11:47:59 2018 0514.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   24140 Oct 26 11:47:59 2018 0515.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   24352 Oct 26 11:47:59 2018 0516.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   24616 Oct 26 11:48:05 2018 0517.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   25002 Oct 26 11:48:05 2018 0518.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   25183 Oct 26 11:48:05 2018 0519.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   24436 Oct 26 11:48:05 2018 0520.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   22747 Oct 26 11:48:05 2018 0521.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   22824 Oct 26 11:48:05 2018 0522.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   24438 Oct 26 11:48:05 2018 0523.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   22419 Oct 26 11:48:05 2018 0524.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   21528 Oct 26 11:48:06 2018 0525.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   25551 Oct 26 11:48:06 2018 0526.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   24156 Oct 26 11:48:06 2018 0527.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   26425 Oct 26 11:48:06 2018 0528.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   26995 Oct 26 11:48:06 2018 0529.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   25376 Oct 26 11:48:06 2018 0530.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   30123 Oct 26 11:48:06 2018 0531.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   29040 Oct 26 11:48:06 2018 0532.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   27235 Oct 26 11:48:06 2018 0533.jpg
-rw-r--r--    1 bolandrm  staff   27163 Oct 26 11:48:06 2018 0534.jpg`

(note the timestamps)

Is there another way to accomplish this that would give real time results?  Ideally, 3 images should be saved to disk per second.

Comment: Add `-flush_packets 1` and check.

Comment: @Gyan no noticeable difference

Comment: Add -report to your command attempt and share report